webkit-linear-gradient :: Setting Relative Colors With Javascript
My goal is to retain the same distance between the colors by any given color.
So in that specific case I want to set the end color to:
#bb0303,
and get
#e13c3b,
without the need to set it statically off-course :)
(or vice versa)
so iow...
I need the mathematical equation to set one color and get the other one RELATIVELY to that color.
So the start given color #bb0303 would set #e13c3b at the end color.
(OR vice versa)
the end given color #e13c3b would set #bb0303 at the the start color.
Here is my code:
function setRelativeColor(myElement,refColor)
{
    myElement.style.background='-webkit-linear-gradient(270deg,#e13c3b 0%,#'+refColor+' 100%)';
}


const myDiv=document.createElement('div');

myDiv.style.width='300px';
myDiv.style.height='80px';

setRelativeColor(myDiv,'bb0303');

document.body.appendChild(myDiv);


Sounds like hsl might be better than hex.

Your colors are hsl(0, 97%, 37%) & hsl(0, 73%, 56%).... start there.

or rgb(187,3,3) & rgb(255,60,59)... enjoy!
